# Verilog simulation errors

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In the simulation, 'a' won't be change its value and I can't seem to know why.
'carry out(co)' always comes out as HiZ, and the 'sum' creates a bit weird values. 'of(overflow)' value as well
Can anybody help me out with this?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
    `timescale 100ps/1ps    
module RCA_tb;
reg [7:0] a;
reg [7:0] b;
reg ci;
wire [7:0] sum;
wire co;
wire of; //overflow
integer i;

RippleCA RCA(a,b,ci,sum,co,of); 

initial begin 

    a=0;
    b=0;
    ci=0;

    end



    initial begin // all possible cases 

    for(i=0; i<256; i=i+1)


    #10 {a, b, ci} = i;


    end
endmodule

module RippleCA(a,b,ci,sum,co,of);
input [7:0] a;
input [7:0] b;
input ci;
output [7:0] sum;
output co;
output of;
wire[6:0] c;
FullAdder a1(a[0],b[0],ci,sum[0],c[0]);
FullAdder a2(a[1],b[1],c[0],sum[1],c[1]);
FullAdder a3(a[2],b[2],c[1],sum[2],c[2]);
FullAdder a4(a[3],b[3],c[2],sum[3],c[3]);
FullAdder a5(a[4],b[4],c[3],sum[4],c[4]);
FullAdder a6(a[5],b[5],c[4],sum[5],c[5]);
FullAdder a7(a[6],b[6],c[5],sum[6],c[6]);
FullAdder a8(a[7],b[7],c[6],sum[7],cout);
xor x2(of,c[6],co); //overflow detection
endmodule
module FullAdder (
a,b,ci,sum,co
);
input a,b,ci;
output sum,co;
wire w1, w2, w3;
xor x1(sum, a, b, ci);
and a1(w1,a,b);
and a2(w2,b,ci);
and a3(w3,ci,a);
or o1(co,w1,w2,w3);
endmodule
```

This is my Verilog code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar91I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzhAn.png)

Comment: Merge 3 initial blocks of testbench to a single one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. just edited my code and simulated it, 'ci' changes every #10 but the other problems remain the same. especially 'a' won't change, and sum produces values including xs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared

```
reg [7:0] a;
reg [7:0] b;
reg ci;
```

And assigned

```
{a, b, ci} = i;
```

`{a,b,ci}` is 17 bits wide but you are counting `i` to up to `255` which is 8 bits wide, in this case `a` will always be zero. If you increase your for loop to `for(i=0; i<262144; i=i+1)` you should be able to test it.